# Can I use `tape` testing tool with Angular2 Testbed?

Tags: javascript, angular, tap

Reading https://medium.com/javascript-scene/why-i-use-tape-instead-of-mocha-so-should-you-6aa105d8eaf4#.z023p7yvd I thought I'd give tape a shot for my Angular2-evaluation project.
But using Testbed with `import {TestBed, async} from '@angular/core/testing';`
 in a tape test file does not seem to work out directly. Compiling the TS file works, but with errors, running the js file gives zone errors. I will not bother you with the code yet. My question is a more principal one:
Has anyone used tape with Angular2-Testbed? Or is there another easy way to use tape for Angular2 unit tests without Testbed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've received an answer from Eric Eliott on this: https://medium.com/@_ericelliott/probably-not-worth-the-trouble-d72fabf3126f#.284702cy1

Seems to be a sensible approach to use just the tools, `ng` comes with (Jasmine, Karma). After I switched back to them, the next problem popped up: [angular-cli: Karma-Webpack bails with 'no such file or directory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648589/angular-cli-karma-webpack-bails-with-no-such-file-or-directory)

But this question here is closed in my humble opinion.