# angular-cli: Karma-Webpack bails with 'no such file or directory'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

I started with the `Tour of Heroes` with standard Angular/systemjs. Now I'm using `angular-client` for it and it runs smoothly in dev/prod mode. But I cannot test anything with `ng test`. The following gets spit out (not only for `test.ts` but also for `polyfills.ts`).

```
code: 'ENOENT',
errno: 34,
message: 'no such file or directory',
path: '/_karma_webpack_/src/test.ts' }
```

I was not able to track it really down, when I started a blank project with `ng`, as soon as I put some component into the `app-routing.module.ts` the error occurred. Pretty sure, that I missed something cpmpletely obvious, so my apologies in advance for that.

If you *really* like to look deeply into the code (or try to run the tests): https://github.com/ckpinguin/angular-tour-of-heroes

Additional info: Before the above error, every component fails with a message like that. I have no clue why, as I can run the app smoothly.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/heroes/hero-list.component/hero-list.component.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getChildAt' of undefined
at refactor.findAstNodes.filter.forEach (/home/axcka01/projects/angular/tour-of-heroes/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:221:54)
at Array.forEach (native)
at _removeModuleId (/home/axcka01/projects/angular/tour-of-heroes/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:215:10)
at Promise.resolve.then.then (/home/axcka01/projects/angular/tour-of-heroes/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:298:33)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts 19:30-89
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi ./src/main.ts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I looked into my Angular book and found out, that all (implicitly) used components have to be declared in the `spec.ts`. As I'm testing the central master-component by using `app.component.spec.ts`, that means no less than using this:

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
    ],
    declarations: [ // TODO: Mock some components!
        AppComponent, HeroListComponent, HeroDetailComponent,
        DashboardComponent, HeroSearchComponent, HeroAddComponent
    ],
}).compileComponents()
```

...instead of just having the `AppComponent` in the declaration!

So the error was nothing else than karma's (confusing) way to say: „I need to load components, but cannot use them, because they're not declarated in this test case.“ (please just correct me if I'm wrong).

I know, normally one should not test „The mother of all components“ with all sub-components. Instead one would only test the smallest set or using mocks. But with the above change in `app.component.spec.ts`, the vanilla ng-cli test cases at least run now.